# Log in verification in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

What I'm trying to do is to start a new session if there's no user logged in and if someone it's logged in it should redirect to a page (loginsucces.jsp) where they gonna see the actual person that is currently logged in. The problem is that if I put this code it's totally working:

```
  <%
   if ( session.isNew() )
   {
     out.println( "<h3>NB: New session starting</h3>" );
  }
  else
  {
    session.invalidate();
%>
    <jsp:forward page="example91.jsp" />
<%
  }
%>
```

This should be the code I want to implement but it's not working ...

```
<%
  if ( session.isNew() )
  {
    out.println( "<h1>New session starting </h1>" );
  }
  else (session.is)
  {
    out.println( "<h1>You are already logged in!");
  }
%>
    <jsp:forward page="userlogin.jsp" />
<%
    <jsp:forward page="loginsucces.jsp" />
%>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 48 in the jsp file: /userlogin.jsp
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
45:     %>
46:         <jsp:forward page="userlogin.jsp" />
47:     <%
48:         <jsp:forward page="loginsucces.jsp" />
49:     %>
50: 
51:     <%

Comment: What is confusing about that error? Perhaps articulate that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see two immediate errors in your code. Refer to the inline comments.

```
<%
  if ( session.isNew() )
  {
    out.println( "<h1>New session starting </h1>" );
  }
  else (session.is) // TYPO HERE
  {
    out.println( "<h1>You are already logged in!");
  }
%>
    <jsp:forward page="userlogin.jsp" />

// THIS JSP TAG SHOULD NOT BE INSIDE <% %>
<%
    <jsp:forward page="loginsucces.jsp" />
%>
```

Comment: Ok, solved! But where I should put the else redirection (<jsp:forward page="loginsucces.jsp" />) ?